# Capitalization of multi-word geographical feature (river basin)

Tags: capitalization, names, toponyms

I understand the stylistic rules for capitalizing the word "river" in a place name, but I can't seem to find any consistent guidelines on whether to capitalize the word "basin" when it follows an instance where "river" should be capitalized.

example:

"The Hooseywhatsit River Basin is home to several species of platypus."

or

"The Hooseywhatsit River basin is home to several species of platypus."

Comment: I use a simple test. If I see it named as a Basin, I follow that. If I am the one who wants to talk about the river basin, and did not otherwise see it with caps, I don't need caps.Then it's like I am talking about the river bank, or the Red River bank.

Comment: From [ICPDR.org](https://www.icpdr.org/main/danube-basin/river-basin): 'The Danube River Basin is Europe's second largest river basin ...' BUT from [USDA.gov](https://www.nrcs.usda.gov/wps/portal/nrcs/detail/national/programs/initiatives/?cid=stelprdb1117397): 'The Red River basin spans 25 million acres ...'. I'd say it's not set in tablets of stone; go with what you find more common (but be consistent within a document).

Comment: What @Edwin said. But note [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Danube+River+Basin%2CDanube+River+basin%2CDanube+river+basin&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CDanube%20River%20Basin%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CDanube%20River%20basin%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CDanube%20river%20basin%3B%2Cc0) suggesting that the "all words capitalised" version (previous the *least* common), has in the past couple of decades shot up to pole position for ***Danube River Basin***.

Comment: @FF It's hard to avoid titles, which comprise a lot of the examples.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  I'm going with "The Hooseywhatsit River Basin" when it's a proper name, and "logging in the basin is threatening the platypus" otherwise.

Comment: In the context of a [defined region with special regulations, restrictions, or treaty agreements](http://www.icpdr.org/main/activities-projects/danube-river-basin-management-plan-2009), then it makes sense to capitalize it. Otherwise, basin is normally just a common noun with perhaps a proper adjective in front. The US GNIS database does list about 2000 locations with *Basin* in the name, but there are only 5 for "River Basin" in reference to actual river basins.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a hard and fast rule.

• [An Ngram comparison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=River+Basin%3Aeng_us_2012%2Criver+basin%3Aeng_us_2012%2CRiver+Basin%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Criver+basin%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CRiver%20Basin%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Criver%20basin%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CRiver%20Basin%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Criver%20basin%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) shows that "River Basin" is more common in American English but "river basin" is more common in British English.

• [Alaska's very through guide to capitalization of geographic terms](https://www.adfg.alaska.gov/static/home/library/pdfs/writersguide_section5.pdf) recommends lower case for compound nouns like "river basin", "river mouth", etc. but capitals when it's just the river's proper name – so "Yukon River" but "Yukon river basin".

• [The Chicago Manual of Style (section 8.53)](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/search.html?clause=rivers) uses "River" in caps as part of the proper name but "basin" in lowercase because it's a modifier: the Mississippi River valley, the Amazon basin, the Mississippi delta.

Comment: Um, no, *basin* isn't a modifier - *basin* is the common noun. It is being modified by *Mississippi River*, which is here being used as a proper adjective.